# Where to implement CSS previously implemented by CSS_editor now deprecated

Tags: theming, flags

[image: Theme css in use]Views with tables have a Flag that changes from Pending to Complete when the row is completed.  The
background of the entire row changes color depending upon the word.

Working css_editor code (theme settings custom CSS enabled):

```
tr.pending td { color: red; }
tr.Complete td { background-color: #66ff99; }
```

After uninstalling the deprecated css_editor module, I have no idea where to put the above code.  Already added to existing custom module css and it does not work as shown. (maybe syntax issue?)
I do not sub-class the theme as this is the only issue. I do have a custom module with css.

Comment: `I do have a custom module with css.` Create one.

Comment: Is it a custom theme? If so it seems you would want to add CSS to the theme, which is documented: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml

Comment: `tr.pending td { color: red !important; }`. Does complete really write with upper C?  `tr.Complete td { background-color: #66ff99 !important; }`.

Comment: The code is currently working.. being used everyday for years.  As written.

Comment: I do not have a custom theme

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector might be a D10 compatible replacement for your other module